# How to run a new command when ssh disconnects?

Tags: 18.04, ssh

we are working on a project and we connect our robot with ssh, but when our robot goes far away from the router, ssh disconnects and our robot keeps publishing last data to motors, so is there a way to stop the motors when ssh disconnects?

For example while i have ssh connection our robot publish velocity data to motors, but when we disconnect i want our robot to publish zero to motors.

Our robot uses Ubuntu 18.04 and i use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for having time to answer, but i did not understand how he solved that problem. All i need is to run a simple command when ssh disconnects, so i assume i need to take ssh connection as an argument.